# Check if an object is an instance of a class (but not an instance of its subclass)

Tags: java, instanceof

For this example:

```
public class Foo{}

public class Bar extends Foo{}

....

void myMethod(Foo qux){
   if (checkInstance(qux,Foo.class)){
     ....
   }
}
```

How can I check if `qux` is an instance of Foo (but not an instance of its subclass of foo)? That is:

- checkInstance(qux,Foo.class)=true
- checkInstance(qux,Bar.class)=false

Is there some kind of statement like `instanceof` for this check? or I should use `qux.getClass().equals(Foo.class)`

Comment: Hope this helps http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=332 You can use `qux instanceof Foo`

Comment: @Selvin Using instanceof does not necessarily mean the app design is wrong. For example it is used in adapters when you are trying to map data to multiple view types.

Comment: but checking if object is instance of Foo but not Bar(when Bar extends Foo) is wrong app design

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you have to do this, the only way would be the `getClass().equals(Foo.class)` option you've suggested.

However, the goal of OO design is to allow you to treat *any* `Foo` in the same fashion. Whether or not the instance is a subclass should be irrelevant in a normal program.

Comment: I think a lot of stack exchange questions are about situations that are out of the normal.

Comment: @WarrenDew I agree. But a high proportion are people seeking a way to implement their own solution to a problem, when perhaps a better solution exists. When you find yourself breaking OO principles in an OO language, it's a pretty good indication you're off piste.

Comment: I don't understand what is a _better alternative_ that is _congruent with OO principles_

Comment: hmm, I guess separating `Foo` into 2 classes `Foo` and `SuperFoo`and have `Bar` descend from `SuperFoo` might be some way to fudge it but the code would become more complicated because of that. So it might be more OO but i'm not so sure it is better.

Comment: ok since I have an IDE that can refactor, that is what I'll do ) maybe it will save me from some bugs in the future (althpugh I prefer the prefix `Abstract` to `Super`, it's just I can't edit old comments)

Comment: In a unit test you would probably want to test for exact class, and not use `instanceof`

Comment: How about the case when you're overriding the `equals` function? I need to be sure that the object I am comparing my object to, is of the same class, and not of a subclass. I do not want a `Manager` object to be equal to an `Employee` object. Otherwise, that would violate the the characteristic of a good `equals` function: "x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true".

Comment: Yea, I appreciate the answer but on SO you really need to avoid assuming _why_ the OP is asking and suggesting they are doing something wrong.
There are plenty of valid cases for this need.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for exact class match the only means is `qux.getClass().equals(Foo.class)`. instanceof will also return true for subclasses.

Answer (score 5):

you should use instanceof

```
if(qux instanceof Foo && !(qux instanceof Bar)) {
    ...
}
```

This works with both classes and interfaces, so in most cases it should preferred over `.class` which does not work with interfaces.

Comment: This won't catch the situation where `Baz` is a subclass of `Foo`.

Comment: is that so? the rhs of the `&&` should return false for instances of `Bar` no matter what other classes it extends

Comment: Assume `Baz` is a direct subclass of `Foo`. Both sides of your `if` clause will then evaluate to `true`.

Comment: you do see the `!`, do you?

Comment: Yes, I do. `Baz` is not an instance of `Bar` in my example. Note that I'm slightly extending the OP's original example to discuss the general case.

Comment: okay misunderstood the OP. Thought he wanted to rule out just a single subclass and let the other subclasses still behave just like the base class and i still don't know why one should want to do it this way

Comment: Upvoting this answer since as currently worded the question is ambiguous whether the OP is asking about the specific `Bar` subclass of `Foo` or any subclass of `Foo`.  "its" in "but not a instance of its subclass of foo" doesn't really tell me if they mean "any subclass" or "the specific subclass I'm about to mention".

Answer (score 2):

I just tried following code, it seems like working fine

```
public class BaseClass {

    private String a;

    public boolean isInstanceOf(BaseClass base){
        if(base == null){
            return false;
        }
        else if(getClass() == base.getClass()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}



public class DervidClass extends BaseClass {


    public boolean isInstanceOf(DervidClass base) {
        if(base == null){
            return false;
        }
        else if(getClass() == base.getClass()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


}

public class myTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {


        BaseClass base = new BaseClass();
        BaseClass base1 = new BaseClass();
        DervidClass derived = new DervidClass();

        BaseClass d1 = new DervidClass();

        System.out.println(base.isInstanceOf(d1));
        System.out.println(d1.isInstanceOf(d1));
        System.out.println((d1 instanceof BaseClass));


    }
```

Comment: Way too much code. You can shorten it to "return getClass() == base.getClass()" or do without your method altogether.

Comment: I don't even understand why you need an instance of the base class. You already know the base class. So that's enough: "return getClass() == BaseClass.class".

Answer (score 2):

I have read all the answers which have been posted so far but couldn't find satisfactory answer yet. Answering to **Is there some kind of statement like `instanceof` for this check? or I should use `qux.getClass().equals(Foo.class)`** question I would say yes, there is `instanceof` operator in java to check if the object is instance of class. Below is an example-:

```
class Vehicle {

}

class Car extends Vehicle {

}

public class Research {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

        if (vehicle instanceof Vehicle) {
            System.out.println("vehicle instanceof Vehicle : TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("vehicle instanceof Vehicle : FALSE");
        }

        if (vehicle instanceof Car) {
            System.out.println("vehicle instanceof Car : TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("vehicle instanceof Car : FALSE");
        }

        System.out.println();
        Car car = new Car();

        if (car instanceof Vehicle) {
            System.out.println("car instanceof Vehicle : TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("car instanceof Vehicle : FALSE");
        }

        if (car instanceof Car) {
            System.out.println("car instanceof Car : TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("car instanceof Car : FALSE");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output-:**

```
vehicle instanceof Vehicle : TRUE
vehicle instanceof Car : FALSE

car instanceof Vehicle : TRUE
car instanceof Car : TRUE
```

**Description-:**`instanceof` operator tells if an object is a instance of a class or it's parent classes (up to any level).
`vehicle instanceof Car : FALSE` line of output is indicating that `instanceof` operator will not tell if an object is a instance of its sub class.

Another way is to use `getClass().equals(Foo.class)` to determine if an object is a instance of a class or not. Let us see below example-:

```
class Vehicle {

}

class Car extends Vehicle {

}

public class Research {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

        if (vehicle.getClass().equals(Vehicle.class)) {
            System.out.println("vehicle instanceof Vehicle : TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("vehicle instanceof Vehicle : FALSE");
        }

        if (vehicle.getClass().equals(Car.class)) {
            System.out.println("vehicle instanceof Car : TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("vehicle instanceof Car : FALSE");
        }

        System.out.println();
        Car car = new Car();

        if (car.getClass().equals(Vehicle.class)) {
            System.out.println("car instanceof Vehicle : TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("car instanceof Vehicle : FALSE");
        }

        if (car.getClass().equals(Car.class)) {
            System.out.println("car instanceof Car : TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("car instanceof Car : FALSE");
        }


    }
}
```

**Output-:**

```
vehicle instanceof Vehicle : TRUE
vehicle instanceof Car : FALSE

car instanceof Vehicle : FALSE
car instanceof Car : TRUE
```

**Description-:** It would be clear from the above example that which one(out of above two) should be opted where?

> Important Notes-:

1. `instanceof` operator will not throw `NullPointerException` exception in case if reference variable is not pointing to any object(i.e. its having null reference).
2. `car.getClass().equals(Car.class)` will throw `NullPointerException` exception in case if `car` is not pointing to any object(i.e. its having null reference). Therefore one must place extra null check with this for example `car != null && car.getClass().equals(Car.class)` to prevent it from `NullPointerException`.
3. `instanceof` operator tells if an object is a instance of a class or it's parent classes (up to any level).
4. `car.getClass().equals(Car.class)` will tell if an object is a instance of class only. **(Parent & Sub classes will not be considered at all)**

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.instance;

    public class Foo {
        public void instance(Foo f) {
            System.out.println("---------");
            System.out.println(f.getClass());
            System.out.println(getClass());
            if (f.getClass() == getClass()) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
            }
        }
    }


package com.instance;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f1 = new Foo();
        Foo f2 = new Foo();
        Foo f3 = new Bar();
        f1.instance(f1);
        f1.instance(f2);
        f1.instance(f3);
    }

}
```

Comment: A picture may paint a thousand words, but a big lump of code sure makes an ugly answer.

Comment: Where did you get the Bar class?

Answer (score 0):

Well you already know that qux is instanceof Foo (unless it's null...), so a simple `qux instanceof Bar` and a null check should be all you need.