# PHP instanceof - return TRUE only for children

Tags: php

I have two classes, A and B. B extends class A.

If I execute `instance of A` on an instance of `B`, it returns `TRUE`.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: This is exactly how it should work. Use 'instanceOf B' otherwise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688655/check-if-a-object-is-a-instance-of-a-class-but-not-a-instance-of-a-subclass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how `instanceof` works, and correctly so: if B inherits from A, it is also of type A.

However, you can check the precise class by using [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) instead:

```
if (get_class($b_instance) == 'A') {
    // Not true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check class by get_class function

```
if( get_class($Binst) == 'A' ) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to know the Class name of an object.

Try to use `get_class($Object)`.

Example:

$objA = new A();
$objB = new B();

`get_class($objA)`
will return "A".

and

`get_class($objB)`
will return "B".

Then if you use

`if (get_class($objB) == "A") { echo "Its a A"; }`

Answer (score 1):

Use `is_subclass_of()` function: `is_subclass_of($b, 'A')`