# Python determine if isintance without checking superclass

Tags: python

```
class A:
   pass

class B(A):
   pass
```

How can I check that `var` is instance of `B`, not `A`, without referencing `A`. I have around 50 classes that subclass some class. I want to check whether instance is a child.
Something like `not isinstance(var, A)`.

Is there any way?

Comment: `B` specifically, or any subclass of `A`? (If any subclass of `A`, why do you want to avoid referring to `A` explicitly?)

Comment: Perhaps you could try look at the `var.__mro__`

Comment: Why without referencing `A`?

Comment: Please clarify. To me it's not quite clear whether you want to check if it's an instance of `B` specifically, or of any class derived from `A` (but not `A` itself). What's the point of _"without referencing `A`"_ ? Have you considered implementing `A` as an _abstract base class_?

Comment: why not `type(x) is A`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isinstance(object, classinfo)` checks if the object is an instance of (or subclass of) the class given as second parameter.

`type(object)` returns the exact type of the object.

So you can check whether the object is an instance of a subclass of `A`, but not `A` itself, you can do something like the following.

```
if isinstance(obj, A) and not type(obj) == A:
    print("is subclass of A")
else:
    print("is either A or completely unrelated")
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that `B` does something particular that `A` can't do. Ie it has a method that `A` doesn't. So one way to check that the instance is from `B` is to use the following.

```
if hasattr(my_instance, 'method_name_particular_to_b'):
    # do this
```

This will check if that method exists on `my_instance` if it does. You can treat it as an instance from `B`, otherwise treat it as an instance from `A`.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to use `isinstance` and judge whether a particular variable `var` is an instance of a subclass or superclass. What you can in fact do is specify a special property `__class__` which can tell you about the instance's class.

for example:

```
class A:
    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return '__main__.A'

class B(A):
    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return '__main__.B'

b = B()
a = A()

print b.__class__
> '__main__.B'

print a.__class__
> '__main__.A'
```

If you however inherit `class A` with `object` you can check the behaviour without specifying these properties.

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
a = A()

print b.__class__
> '__main__.B'

print a.__class__
> '__main__.A'
```

PS: I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688655/check-if-a-object-is-a-instance-of-a-class-but-not-a-instance-of-its-subclass) SO question although it is in Java

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but seems working: `not var.__class__.__name__=='A'`

Comment: @user2357112 That wont work. If `var = B()`, `not isinstance(var, A)` returns `False`.

Comment: @pstatix: Bleh, right. Got mixed up there. Should be `var.__class__ is not A`, which is a solution the questioner probably wasn't aware of.

Comment: Is `var.__class__` better than `type(var)`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: It handles old-style classes, which the questioner may be using.

Comment: (`isinstance(var, A) and var.__class__ is not A` to check specifically for subclasses and reject superclasses and unrelated classes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the type of an instance using `__class__`.

`var.__class__` will give you the specific type of the object.