# Java instanceOf Class not comparing as expected

Tags: java, generics, factory-pattern

I have the following code,

```
public <T> T build(Object source, Class<T> destClass) {
        if((Object)destClass instanceof TestDTO){
            return (T) testBuilder.build((BlahDTO) source);
        }
        if((Object)destClass instanceof BestDTO) {
            return (T) bestBuilder.build((BlahDTO) source);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am trying to compare if the destClass if either of the type TestDTO or BestDTO and take the appropriate action. But the comparison fails even though the destClass is of the specified type. Am I missing something, also my alternate approach,

```
public <T> T build(Object source, Class<T> destClass) {
        if(destClass.getSimpleName().equals(TestDTO.class.getSimpleName())){
            return (T) testBuilder.build((BlahDTO) source);
        }
        if(destClass.getSimpleName().equals(BestDTO.class.getSimpleName())) {
            return (T) bestBuilder.build((BlahDTO) source);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

although this approach works, I find this code a bit dicey. It would be helpful if someone pointed out what I was doing wrong, or suggest an alternate approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that a class is _not_ an instance of a class and casting a class to `Object` does _not_ make it an instance either. Use `Class.isAssignableFrom()` instead.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688655/check-if-a-object-is-a-instance-of-a-class-but-not-a-instance-of-its-subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceof` checks to see if the left-hand operand is an **instance of** the right-hand operand. But your left-hand operand is a `Class` object, not an instance of that class. To use `instanceof`, you must have an *instance* of the class (something created via `new TheClass`).

As [Thomas points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884853/java-instanceof-class-not-comparing-as-expected/46884891#comment80716993_46884853), if you really mean to be working with `Class` instances, you may want [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) instead:

```
if (TestDTO.class.isAssignableFrom(destClass))
```

---

Side note: There's no purpose served by the `(Object)` cast on `if((Object)destClass instanceof TestDTO)`. `instanceof` checks the *object*, not the kind of reference you have to it; casting is irrelevant to that check.