# How to get the statically binded class in Java?

Tags: java, overriding, dynamic-binding, dynamic-dispatch, static-binding

Say

```
class E extends B {}
class B extends A {}
```

We have,

```
B v = new E();
process(v);
```

We know it is true that,

```
v.getClass() == E.class
```

Is there a way to tell the static binding for v is exactly B programmatically?

EDIT: 
  The original idea was to have a one line check for overloaded methods.
  Something like,

```
   process(A a) {
     // ... code for a.processABC();
     if (a.getStaticBindingClass() == B.class) { // not a subclass of B
        // Additional logic for statical binding case.
         ... 
     }
     // ... code for a.processDEF();
   }
```

It is possible to introduce process(B b); However, there is lots of copy code from process(A a).

Comment: It depends on how you are using `v`. Is it a field?

Comment: v is a local variable in some methods. Why does it matter whether v is a field or not?

Comment: could you give more info on the context? what you want to do?

Comment: If it's a local variable, it may not even *exist* by the time the code is JITted: the JIT could inline, stack-allocate, enregister, etc. You need to show the code that's using `v` and wants to know its static type.

Comment: `B.class.isAssignable(v.getClass())`?

Comment: The question is: why would you do that? It might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a object is a instance of a class (but not a instance of its subclass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688655/check-if-a-object-is-a-instance-of-a-class-but-not-a-instance-of-its-subclass)

Comment: Edited the original question. The difference if the  
Possible duplicate one is here I need an exact match case and a subclass.

Comment: You need to look up the Visitor pattern.