# KafkaException: class is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to implement Kafka producer which sends and receives Java Serialized Objects. I tried this:

***Producer:***

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactory.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactory.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    /*
        Serialization configuration
     */
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

```java
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
}
```

***Send object:***

```java
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;

private static String topic = "tp-sale";

private void perform(){

    SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
    obj.setId(100);

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory>> send = saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate.send(topic, obj);
}
```

***Consumer:***

```java
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleResponseFactory.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

// Receive Object

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
public SaleResponseFactory transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(tf.getId());

    SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
    resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

    return resObj;
}
```

When I deploy the Producer I get error during deployment:

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: class org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer`

Custom object

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable, Serializer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
    private int id;

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String s, Object o) {
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

```java
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
    
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleResponseFactory implements Serializable, Deserializer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;

    private String unique_id;

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

***EDIT:***  I tried this:

***Producer:***

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactorySerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

```java
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
}
```

***Send object:***

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;

private static String topic = "tp-sale";

private void perform(){

    SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
    obj.setId(100);

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory>> send = saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate.send(topic, obj);
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

// Receive Object

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
public SaleResponseFactory transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(tf.getId());

    SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
    resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

    return resObj;
}
```

***Custom objects***

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
    private int id;
}

public class SaleRequestFactorySerializer implements Serializable, Serializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, SaleRequestFactory data) {
        // convert data to byte[]
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

​

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleResponseFactory implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;

    private String unique_id;
}

public class SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleResponseFactory> {

    @Override
    public SaleResponseFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        // convert data to SaleResponseFactory
        SaleResponseFactory saleResponseFactory = null;
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            saleResponseFactory = (SaleResponseFactory) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saleResponseFactory;
    }
}
```

When I try to send message I get error:

```java
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition tp-sale-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: null
21:27:51.152 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer[debug:296] - Commit list: {}
21:27:51.153 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer[error:149] - Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:145)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:103)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1265)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1022)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition tp-sale-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: null
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

***EDIT:***
I managed to implement these improvements:

***Producer:***

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactorySerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

```java
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
}
```

***Send object:***

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;

private static String topic = "tp-sale";

private void perform(){

    SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
    obj.setId(100);

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory>> send = saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate.send(topic, obj);
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

***Receive Object***

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
public SaleResponseFactory transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(tf.getId());

    SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
    resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

    return resObj;
}
```

***Custom objects***

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
    private int id;
}

public class SaleRequestFactorySerializer implements Serializable, Serializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, SaleRequestFactory data) {
        // convert data to byte[]
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

​

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleResponseFactory implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;

    private String unique_id;
}

public class SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleResponseFactory> {

    @Override
    public SaleResponseFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        // convert data to SaleResponseFactory
        SaleResponseFactory saleResponseFactory = null;
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            saleResponseFactory = (SaleResponseFactory) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saleResponseFactory;
    }
}
```

When I send some message I get error:

```java
13:03:53.675 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter[debug:296] - Listener method returned result [org.factory.SaleResponseFactory@69c400ab] - generating response message for it
13:03:53.675 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter[debug:296] - No replyTopic to handle the reply: org.factory.SaleResponseFactory@69c400ab
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Does this anser your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688655/check-if-a-object-is-a-instance-of-a-class-but-not-a-instance-of-its-subclass

Comment: You should separate your objects being serialized from the actual serializer classes, and they don't need to be called "factories"

Comment: Can you show me code example, please?

Comment: You already have it, but fix the naming `SaleRequestSerializer implements org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer`... My point is that your ProducerFactory, for example shouldn't be "sending" your serializer, so have a separate class `ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using different type to cast the object than what it was serialize with. Not sure why you need to do that. You can update your deserialize to something like below.

```
public class SaleRequestFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

     @Override
     public SaleRequestFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
      ...
        saleRequestFactory = (SaleRequestFactory) in.readObject();

    }
}
```

> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: null
> ```

This also means your serialization didn't work as expected. Make sure you have valid payload before you try to cast.

Comment: This is the solution. One additional question: Do I need to add flush like this: `ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.flush();
            out.close();` in order to prevent memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG is a class which deserializes the network value into proper Java classes. The class you provided doesn't do that.

In most cases, StringDeserializer is used. Specify a proper deserializer to the factory properties.

Comment: I updated the code. Now I get `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: class org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer`

Comment: "In most cases, StringDeserializer is used." - This is false for custom objects without a toString implementation

Comment: You either need to use a deserialiser provided by the Kafka driver, or make your class implement org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.

See https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html for the documentation around this interface.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using application.properties for kafka configuration parameters, make sure it looks like it

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:8888
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=message
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:8888
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```